# Is there a way to access a single element in an many to many ActiveRecord association via form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

Hello Ruby on Rails professionals out there!

In a project we work with Ruby on Rails (version 6.1.1) and we have a database model with the associations as in the screenshot ([Database UML with ActiveRecord Associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v39GI.png)). This UML diagram shows three models in Ruby, **Task**, **UserTask** and **User**.

**[UserTask](https://github.com/ToDoGether/webapp/blob/feature/personal-notes/app/models/user_task.rb)** has an ID, task_id as foreign key (via association `belongs_to :task`) and user_id as foreign key (via association `belongs_to :user`). It also has an ActionText linked to it, it is called personal_note and according to the guide on [rubyonrails.org](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html) it has the association `has_rich_text :personal_note`.

**[Task](https://github.com/ToDoGether/webapp/blob/feature/personal-notes/app/models/task.rb)** has the association `has_many :user_tasks` and `has_many :users, through: :user_tasks`.

**[User](https://github.com/ToDoGether/webapp/blob/feature/personal-notes/app/models/user.rb)** has the association `has_many :user_tasks` and `has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks`.

I was neither able to define a specific **UserTask** using the current user nor to define a specific UserTask using the current task of a user.

In the form, where we edit the task, we want to also update the personal_note of the current user. But when saving I receive the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :user_task
```

I tried lots of changes with singular and plural, with where conditions and where combined with first and also creating methods that filter the element. Though I wasn't able to fix that and now I have no clue how this may work (or in fact, is there just no way it works at all?). Maybe someone else here has an idea.

You can find the project code in [Github](https://github.com/ToDoGether/webapp/tree/feature/personal-notes), it's in it's own branch.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.